# How to expand Property references in XML Document C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file as something similar to what follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="14.0">
    <PropertyGroup>
       <Property1>DummyProperty</Property1>
       </PropertyGroup>
    <Reference>
       <HintPath>C:\$(Property1)\DummyFile.txt</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</Project>
```

Now when I try to parse this XML in C# (using XElement and XDocument), I need to expand $(Property1) so that the final string that I get for this path is:

> C:\DummyProperty\DummyFile.txt

but I am unable to achieve this and continue to get

> C:\$(Property1)\DummyFile.txt

What is the right way? Is there a different library I should use?
Thank you!

Comment: You can try to use [ProjectRootElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.construction.projectrootelement(v=vs.140).aspx) class from Microsoft.Build.dll for parsing `csproj` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement project = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = project.GetDefaultNamespace();

            string property1 = (string)project.Descendants(ns + "Property1").FirstOrDefault();
            string hintPath = (string)project.Descendants(ns + "HintPath").FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do replacing of `$(Property1)` to `DummyProperty` by yourself.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(pathToTheProjectFile);
var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

var properties = doc.Descendants(ns + "PropertyGroup")
                    .SelectMany(property => property.Elements())
                    .Select(element => new 
                    { 
                        Old = $"$({element.Name.LocalName})", 
                        New = element.Value 
                    });

var hintPathCollection = 
    doc.Descendants(ns + "HintPath")
       .Select(element => properties.Aggregate(element.Value, 
                                               (path, values) => path.Replace(values.Old, values.New)));
```